# 1:1 NAT with nftables on OpenWRT 22.03

Tags: routes, debian, openwrt, nftables

I am running my OpenWrt Router as an OpenVPN Client in a VPN site-to-site setup. After Upgrading to newest OpenWrt 22.03 I have to migrate my firewall coustom rules to nftables. Can you help me finding the nft-file for this:

- /usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i tun+ -d 10.2.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.0/24
- /usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun+ -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 10.2.1.0/24

Con you help? This is not working:

```
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.2.1.0/24 dnat 192.168.1.0/24
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type filter hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 snat 10.2.1.0/24
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided I believe does NAT pooling ([I think that is the correct term](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT))), instead of 1:1 nat. This makes an input `.1` address end up with a random `.0-.255` destination ip for a /24 block.

---

This works for me:

1. ensure firewall allows access to the zone(s) you are trying to access. For example something like this:

```
config forwarding
        option src 'vpn'
        option dest 'lan'

config forwarding
        option src 'lan'
        option dest 'vpn'
```

2. add the following to `/etc/config/firewall`

```
config include
        option type 'nftables'
        option path '/etc/firewall_1to1_nat.nft'
        option position 'ruleset-post'
```

3. create `/etc/firewall_1to1_nat.nft` - this will translate inbound `10.11.0.0/24` to `192.168.0.0/24` and back.

```
table ip NAT1to1
delete table ip NAT1to1
table ip NAT1to1 {
        chain dstnat {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                ip daddr 10.11.0.0/24 iif WIREGUARD counter meta nftrace set 1 dnat ip prefix to ip daddr map { 10.11.0.0/24 : 192.168.0.0/24 }
        }
 
        chain srcnat {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 oif WIREGUARD counter meta nftrace set 1 snat ip prefix to ip saddr map { 192.168.0.0/24 : 10.11.0.0/24 }
        }
}
```

Note: remove the `counter` and `meta nftrace set 1` bits as needed.

Note: this works on `ip` type nftables but not the `inet` type. `inet` tables end with an `Error: Could not process rule: Not supported` message.

Note: for wireguard, the remote end will need to have `10.11.0.0/24` in allowed IPs for this example.

Source: https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=35a6b10c1bc488ca195e9c641563c29251f725f3

4. Also do not forget to update `/etc/sysupgrade.conf` so your backups also contain the updated file.

```
/etc/firewall_defray_1to1_nat.nft
```

edit: corrected error; you cannot flush a table